# Effect of a flipped image on projection matrix and the intrinsic/extrinsic calibration matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

I already asked this question on [StackExchange Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556707/effect-of-a-flipped-image-on-projection-matrix-and-the-intrinsic-extrinsic-calib), but it seems too domain-specific. Searching where to put Computer Vision related questions it was suggested to use Computational Science since there is no specific CV StackExchange branch.

With the [direct linear transform](https://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/html/teaching/msr2-2020/sse2-13-DLT.pdf), one can calibrate a camera and receive the projection matrix, which can be further decomposed in intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters.

For this, at least 6 points need to be clicked on the image of which the 3D coordinates are known.

I wonder what is the effect of a flipped image (left to right) on the projection matrix or on the decomposed parameters?

I have tested this with an image. The resulting two p-matrices do not look similar to me. I hoped that only some signs changes but my intuition was wrong. When checking the decomposed matrices it seems like the intrinsics changes the sign for the x component and the skew of x:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which makes sense.
The rotation matrix seems to have negative signs and multiple places as well:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which makes sense to me when I draw the new axis of the camera, which is now no longer a right-handed coordinate system and seems to be mirrored.

In the end I failed to see a connection between the two translations T that I received from the two decomposed projection matrices. Otherwise, I could have combined K,R and T to receive the "for flipping corrected P" with
$$P_c = K_c [R_c|T_c]$$ with c indicating the correction.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a set of control points for your camera that come from a flipped image and that from these you've extracted your calibration matrices and now you are wondering how you would transform your calibration matrices to correspond to the same control points keyed to an unflipped image?

Comment: @Richard, exactly, that's it.